# Delete from table with(snapshot)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory-optimized-tables, query-store

I was trying to learn querystore. When going through few queries involved in query store one of the query is below

```
DELETE TOP (1000000)
FROM [sys].[memory_optimized_history_table_1179151246]
 WITH (SNAPSHOT)
```

**Full query:**

```
(@rowcount INT OUTPUT) DELETE TOP (1000000) FROM [sys].[memory_optimized_history_table_1179151246] WITH (SNAPSHOT) 
OUTPUT 
DELETED.[ColdRoomTemperatureID], DELETED.[ColdRoomSensorNumber], DELETED.[RecordedWhen], DELETED.[Temperature], DELETED.[ValidFrom], DELETED.[ValidTo]  
 INTO [Warehouse].[ColdRoomTemperatures_Archive]  
 WHERE [ValidTo] < GetHkOldestTxTemporalTs()
```

I searched a lot to see what the `WITH (SNAPSHOT)` option means, but I was not able to find anything.

Can you please help me in understanding what does `WITH (SNAPSHOT)` mean?

Let me know ,if you need any further info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a table hint that can be used in various statements (SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, MERGE). See the related page at msdn: [Table hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) and the linked [Introduction to Memory-Optimized tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn511014.aspx).

For further information about isolation levels, see [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx).

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> WITH  ( <table_hint> [ [, ]...n ] )  
>   
> <table_hint> ::=   
> [ NOEXPAND ] {   
>     INDEX  ( index_value [ ,...n ] )   
>   | INDEX =  ( index_value )      
>   | FORCESEEK [( index_value ( index_column_name  [ ,... ] ) ) ]  
>   | FORCESCAN  
>   ...
>   | SNAPSHOT
>   ...
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `SNAPSHOT`
>
> Applies to: SQL Server 2014 through SQL Server 2016.
>
> **The memory-optimized table is accessed under `SNAPSHOT` isolation.**
> **`SNAPSHOT` can only be used with memory-optimized tables** (not with disk-based tables).
> For more information, see [Introduction to Memory-Optimized Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn511014.aspx).